# Get the size of a array that passed in parameter

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a `cpp` program which takes some double values as input and calculate the total of the values. Length of the array is not stable. It changes with the number of input. So I chose to use `for each` loop inside the function.Following is my code.

```
double getTotal (double arr[]){
   double total = 0;
   for (double x : arr){
      total += x; 
   }
   return total;
}
```

The above code gives me the following error

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘double My1DArray::getTotal(double*)’:
main.cpp:39:28: error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope
        for (double x : arr){
                        ^
```

I tried to use `arr.size()` which gave me a bunch of errors.

What cause the problem?

Comment: You can't, because `double arr[]` decays to merely a pointer and doesn't hold that information. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: It's not really an exact duplicate, but it explains your pointer decay problem well enough.

Comment: @Blaze You mean `vector<double> &arr` something like this?

Comment: @Ramesh That's right. Make the vector like `std::vector<double> arr;`, and for the function signature, put `double getTotal (vector<double> &arr)`.

Comment: @Useless I checked the question before. But the pointer stuffs are really new to me and made me little confused. Can you give me little explanation regarding this.

Comment: @Blaze it saved my time sir. Thank you

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)